# Difficult MySQL self-join please explain

Tags: mysql

This is supposed to be able to return a random post id. It is also said to be the fastest method using MySQL.

```
SELECT t.id 
FROM table t 
JOIN (SELECT(FLOOR(max(id) * rand())) AS maxid FROM table) 
AS tt 
ON t.id >= tt.maxid 
LIMIT 1
```

Can't seem to wrap my head around this, please help.

Comment: where did you get it from? Was there no explanation there?

Comment: Got it from this thread: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,163940,262235#msg-262235.

Comment: The `SELECT(FLOOR(max(id) * rand())) AS maxid FROM table` part selects a random `id` from `table` with only one call to `RAND()`. Not sure why it's `JOIN`'ed, though, as only the `t.id` is selected?!

Comment: And now I'm wiser thanks to @Nanne :)

Comment: Still having trouble understanding it, posted new question with added relevance @ <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733036/how-is-using-join-faster-than-using-just-rand-in-mysql>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pick a random ID number from your table with the "joined table"

```
 SELECT(FLOOR(max(id) * rand())) AS maxid FROM table
```

This will only return something you can use if the id's don't have holes in them (consequtive integers).
THat's why you're joining on this

```
 ON t.id >= tt.maxid
```

You'll get all the id's that are HIGHER then your random number. The limit then gets the first of those.

So an example: say you have these entries in table:
     1, 2, 5, 7, 8.

The floored random number will be smaller then 8, e.g. 3. You'll join will give you 5, 7 and 8 but returns only 5 because of the limit

Answer (score 0):

First, formatting helps

```
1. SELECT t.id 
2.   FROM table t 
3.          JOIN (SELECT(FLOOR(max(id) * rand())) AS maxid FROM table) AS tt 
4.          ON t.id >= tt.maxid 
5. LIMIT 1
```

Let's look at subquery inside JOIN first:

- rand() returns random value in range [0, 1] (e.g. 0.999, 0.251, 1)
- max(id) means that your query will return maximal value of column `id` from specified table
- Floor rounds input number down to the nearest integer (e.g. Floor(5.1) == 5, Floor(5.9) = 5)

hence, the subquery will return you random integer (due to FLOOR) number in the
range [0, 1]

"LIMIT 1" means that your query will return only one row from resulting set.

Hope this enough. Feel free to ask more details

Comment: I don't understand what exactly the join does

Comment: @whamsicore: what `JOIN` does in general, or why you need to join tables in this particular case ?